# How to solve equation $e^x \log x=2$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know how to solve the equation
$$e^x\log x=2.$$
We can get a numerical solution but it seems difficult to get an exact solution. I know the Lambert W function but unable to use it for the above equation.

Comment: $x=1.5372017025783550472\cdots $ --- I'm not sure what you mean by an "exact" solution --- like in terms of some known special function? that is not likely to be forthcoming.

Comment: Is there a closed form solution not only the numerical solution?

Comment: "closed form" in the sense of a known special function: unlikely; however, you could define a new special function $U(a)$ by $e^x \log x=a$, and then the number you seek is $U(2)$.

Comment: Maple does not find a closed form, and Maple is pretty good with the Lambert W, so it seems that W will not help with closed form for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not think that there is any known special function which solves your equation. However, a solution can be given in a sort of 'infinite exponent tower'. More precisely, rewrite the equation as:
$$ \ln x = 2e^{-x} \Rightarrow x = e^{2e^{-x}} $$
Then, the solution is:
$$ x=e^{2e^{-e^{2e^{...}}}} $$
Following a similar idea to the one given by @Carlo Beenakker in the comments, you could then define a function $U$ as follows:
$$ U(a,b,c):= a^{ba^{ ca^{ ba^{ ...}}}} $$
(alternating $b$ and $c$)
Then, you can study when this new function converges. It is clear that the solution to your equation is:
$$ x=U(e,2,-1) \approx 1.537201702578...$$
Notice that the function $U$ is a generalisation of the operation of infinite tetration. Indeed:
$$ U(a,1,1) = a^{a^{a^{ ...}}} = \frac{W(-\ln a)}{- \ln a} $$

EDIT: as noticed by @LSpice, we can even simplify this and consider the function (with only two variables):
$$ Z(a,b) := a^{-2b a^{ba^{ ...}}}$$
(again, alternating) and get:
$$ x=Z(e,-1) $$

Comment: Of course $U$ could be boiled down to a function of $2$ variables; you can just put $x = e^{2U(e, -2)}$, in the obvious notation.

Comment: Yes: this is even better, because you simplify the study of convergence of such new function

Comment: Thanks for your discussion and help!

Comment: It seems to me, from $x=\exp(2\exp(-x))$ we get not what you said, but instead
$$
x = \exp\Bigg(2\exp\bigg(-\exp\Big(2\exp(-\dots)\big)\Big)\bigg)\Bigg)\\
$$
where we alternate coefficnents $2$ and $-1$.

Comment: Thanks for noting this; I have now corrected the answer.